# Responsive css grids and various resolutions?

Tags: css, grid, media-queries

I looked at some css rsponsive grids. I'm currently trying Unsemantic.
I don't really understand how it can manage various resolutions like 400, 768, 1024, while we can only use two kind of classes : grid-XX and mobile-grid-XX.

Unsemantic CSS files contain media queries regarding all the resolutions I mentioned above, but I don't understand how I can use them.

For example, if I have two columns on my main page
I would like them to be 50% wide each on 1024px or more, 70% and 30% wide between 640 and 1024px, and 100% wide on 400px and less.

Is it possible?

Do you know any responsive grid system that could be easier to understand and use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with Unsemantic. However, I have used [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) to do this exact thing before.

Comment: Seems nice. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cascade Framework](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/grid-presentational.html).

Cascade Framework's grid system does exactly what you want. Out of the box, Cascade Framework's grid system supports 60%/40%, 25%/75%, 33.33%/66.66%, 20%/20%/20%/20%/20%, 43.75%/31.25%/25%, 30%/30%/40% and far more combinations. In fact, you can even use combinations like 42.8571429%/{fill to 100%}, {fit content}/{fill to 100%} or {fit content}/30%/{fill to 100%}.

A grid element in Cascade framework is either

- One of the following HTML elements : section, main, article, header, footer, aside or nav (these elements are polyfilled with the HTMLshiv for old IE in case you need it).
- A div element with a 'col' class (can be used in old IE without a polyfill).

To add a width to a grid element, you add a class of the format 'width-XofY', where Y can be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16 or 24 and X can be any value lower than X.

More concretely, here are some examples of valid classes you can use in Cascade Framework : 'width-1of2' (width : 50%), 'width-3of4' (width : 25%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of7' (width:28.5714286%) and 'width-13of16' (width:81.25%)

Additional to these classes, you can also use the classes 'width-fit' and 'width-fill' that respectively fit to content and fill whatever remains of your 100% width. Or, you could just define your own classes and IDs and just add a custom width for those classes to do things the 'semantic' way.

If your build includes the responsiveness module, the width of all grid elements automatic resets to 100% on mobile. You can use classes like 'mobile-width-3of16', 'phone-width-3of7' or 'tablet-width-2of4' to customize the layout for different width ranges and the classes 'desktop-hidden', 'mobile-hidden', 'phone-hidden' or 'tablet-hidden' to hide content for a specific screen with range.

Note that the current version of Cascade Framework is written in pure CSS. That means there is no way (yet) to configure the breakpoints that distinguish between desktop, tablet and phone by just changing a single variable. You can, however, do a copy-replace of these breakpoints with your own custom breakpoints in the source code if you are dissatisfied with the default breakpoints.

See also **http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/grid.html** and **http://jslegers.github.io/responsiveness**/ .